# Debug/Log while file it's looking for and where it's looking

Tags: xcode, lldb

I'm using LLDB on mac and for certain files it's apparently not finding the source as I'm just getting a disassembly. Are then any settings that would help me figure out which file it's trying to find and where it's looking so I could figure out what source-map to define?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've changed your frame format setting, lldb prints the base-name of the source file both in the regular stop printing and in the backtrace.

So stopping in a frame that has a debug info but we can't find the source, you will see something like:

```
frame #0: 0x0000000100003f50 missing_file`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fdff140) at missing_file.c:9:3
```

but no following source.

So you know there's source that comes from file called missing_file.c which lldb can't find.  If you want to know the full path to missing_file.c, do:

(lldb) source info -f missing_file.c

and it will show you the full path, which is what you need for the source map.

If this is a more frequent problem, you can swap `module.file.basename` with `module.file.fullname` in the `frame-format` setting.  Then when you stop in a frame you'll see the full path to the source file immediately.  This isn't the default setting because you don't usually need the full path when stopping, and paths can be long.

lldb doesn't currently have a "announce missing source files searches noisily" mode.  It's pretty easy to guess what's going on, and finding the full path given the source name is also straight-forward.  And the search is pretty simple, it only consults the debug info path, and the `target.source-map`...

So nobody has felt the need for more details from lldb about the search process.  However, if this seems to you a worthwhile addition, please file an ER with the lldb issues tracker:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues

or if you feel adventurous try whipping up something yourself!